# Stairs have 22 steps. If each step were built 1.6 cm higher, two steps could be saved. How high is a step?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Stairs have 22 steps. If each step were built 1.6 cm higher, two steps could be saved. How high is a step in cm?

Comment: You could start by marking step height $=x$. Then consider the total height of the staircase. What equation do you get?

Comment: @MattiP. I am not able to get a solid equation that’s the problem here

Comment: Well, on one hand, the total height is $22x$. The second part says that if the stair height is increased by 1.6 cm, then the total number of steps is two less than 22 (so: 20) in another staircase of the same height. So my question for you is: If the stair height is equal to $x+1.6$, and there are $20$ steps, what is the total height of the staircase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:*
$h =$ height of the stairs, $s =$ height of a step.
$h = 22s = 20(s + 1.6)$.  Is that correct?
Now what?

Comment: Perhaps it is intended as a hint.  I will fix it.